# JSF Delete file after downloading?

Tags: jsf, download

I'm on jsf application, I want to :

1. List the files on X directory(Windows) a JSF componnent.
2. Users can download one those files, and after downloading.
3. Delete the downloaded file from the server.

How can I make this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Example for Primefaces.

1. [Download](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf)
2. [Coose](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadDnd.jsf)
3. Delete -> www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/deletefile.html